# Русская дата, +n дней

Tags: php, дата, datetime

```
<?
$date = new DateTime('+3 day');
$localisedResult = str_replace(
array('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'),
array('января', 'февраля', 'марта', 'апреля', 'мая', 'июня', 'июля', 'августа', 'сентября', 'октября', 'ноября', 'декабря'),
$date->format('j M')
);
echo $localisedResult;
?>
```

Есть ли более лучшее решение?

Comment: Нормальное у вас решение.

Answer (score 1):

```
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');

echo strftime("%A %e %B %Y", strtotime('+3 day'));
// Понедельник 10 Апрель 2017
```

Comment: Еще раз гляньте код и поймите, что он делает. Ваше решение не подходит

Answer (score 0):

Есть функция [`strftime`](https://php.ru/manual/function.strftime.html), которая работает в соответствии с настройками locale. Последняя ставится функцией [`setlocale`](https://php.ru/manual/function.strftime.html).

То есть вы делаете

```
setlocale (LC_TIME, ru_RU);
echo strftime("%B");
```

и должно быть по-русски.

Comment: Еще раз гляньте код и поймите, что он делает. Ваше решение не подходит