# Перевод даты на русский язык из БД

Tags: php, mysql

Всем доброго времени суток.
В бд есть поле "date" такого формата 2017-01-01
Вывожу через функцию date()

```
date('d F', strtotime($article['date']));
```

На выходе получается "01 January" как перевести на русский язык?
Гугл не помог.
Возможно есть какой-нибудь мини фраемворк или библиотека для решения моего вопроса
Заранее благодарю за ответы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/649686/191482

Comment: Если в сессии MySQL сделать `set lc_time_names=ru_RU;` то после этого стандартная функция MySQL `date_format ()` начинает писать на русском. `select date_format(now(),'%d %M')` возвращает "14 Апреля"

Comment: @Mike вопрос не по теме,но раз уж пошла горячая вода - если брать только месяц, есть возможность писать не "Апреля", а "Апрель"? `date_format(now(), '%M')` пишет "Апреля"

Comment: @Denis Думаю нет. Тогда уже придется завести в БД табличку с месяцами и подклеивать в запросе